# Require function inside <script> node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, mongoose-schema

Can i put a require function inside the script tag for example like this:

```
<script>
    var User = require('../models/user');
    alert('It is working');
</script>
```

The above code is my layout.handlebar code. But it seems like it is not working.
Because i need to get this script so that i can access the user.js script on my handlebar template engine.

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    index:true
},
password:{
    type:String
},
email:{
    type:String
},
name:{
    type:String
},
field:{
    type:String
},
e_money:{
    type:Number //this is the integer form in mongoose
}
});

//accesible variable from the outside
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//create the user
module.exports.createUser= function(newUser, callback){
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
    //store hash in your password DB
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(callback);
});
});
}



module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
var query = {username: username};
User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
});
}
```

**EDITED:**
I edit my question because what i really want was when i click the button it will update on my database. here's my whole code for that

**on my routes->users.js**

```
//To run the application
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

//Register
router.get('/register', function(req,res){
res.render('register');
});

//Login
router.get('/login',function(req,res){
res.render('login');
});

//Register User
router.post('/register', function(req,res){
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var password2 = req.body.password2;
var field = req.body.field;

//temporary for emoney
var e_money = req.body.e_money;

//show what's been written in web to console(name)
//console.log(name);

//validation - Check to see if the field is empty
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid!').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Password does not match').equals(req.body.password);
req.checkBody('field', 'Please specify if you are a Teacher or a Student!').notEmpty();

//temporary for emoney
req.checkBody('e_money','Please add some value in this field').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
        errors:errors
    });
}else{
        //new user in the model(user.js)
    var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        field: field,
        e_money: e_money //temporary emoney
    });

    User.createUser(newUser,function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registed and can now login');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
}
});




passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done){
User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
        }
        else{
            return done(null, false, {message: "Invalid password"});
        }
    });
});
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
User.getUserById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err,user);
});
});

router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local',{sucessRedirect:'/',failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
function(req,res){
    //dashboard
    if (req.user.field == "student") {
        req.flash('stud_val', 'student');
    }else if(req.user.field == "teacher"){
        req.flash('teach_val', 'teacher');
    }else if (req.user.field == "admin") {
        req.flash('admin_val', 'teacher');
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/logout',function(req, res){
req.logout();
req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

res.redirect('/users/login');
})


module.exports = router;
```

**and on my views->layout->layout.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{{#if user}}
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<title>PEKTOS | Live Stream</title>
<!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
<link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Waves Effect Css -->
<link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Animation Css -->
<link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Morris Chart Css-->
<link href="plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Custom Css -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
<link href="css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/easyrtc/easyrtc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/easyrtc/labs/easyrtc_recorder.js">    </script>
{{#if stud_val}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo_multistream_stud.js"></script>
{{/if}}
{{#if teach_val}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/easyrtc/labs/desktop_capture_iframe_version.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo_multistream.js"></script>
{{/if}}
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo_instant_messaging_rooms.js"></script> -->

<!-- for button -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>



{{else}}
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Pektos | Log in</title>
  <!-- Favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Select Css -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
  <link href="/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
  <link href="/plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Animation Css -->
  <link href="/plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Custom Css -->
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">



{{/if}}
</head>
<!--Load view-->
{{#if user}}
<body class="theme-red" style="overflow: hidden;">
{{{body}}}
{{else}}
<body class="login-page">
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Pek<b>Tos</b></a>
        <small>Right On Target</small>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="body">
            <form id="sign_in" method="POST">
                <div class="msg">
                  {{#if success_msg}} <!--Global variable that has been set in app.js-->
                  <div class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}
                  </div>
                  {{/if}}
                  {{#if error_msg}}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}
                  </div>
                  {{/if}}
                  {{#if error}}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}
                  </div>
                  {{/if}}
                  {{{body}}}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/if}}
{{#if user}}

<script>

    $('#localVideos').click(function(){
        $('nav').toggle('drop',{direction: 'up'}, 500);
        $('.btnMenuFloat').toggle('drop',{direction: 'left'}, 500);
        $('.actionBtnFloat').toggle('drop',{direction: 'down'}, 500);
        $('.btnfloat').toggle('drop',{direction: 'down'}, 500);
        $('.actionPanel2').hide();
    });

    function muteMe(id) {
        if($('.cv'+id).prop('muted')){
             $('.cv'+id).prop('muted', false);
             var child = document.getElementById("micid"+id);
             child.innerHTML = "mic";
             $('.micbut'+id).css("color", "green");
        }
        else{
             $('.cv'+id).prop('muted', true);
             var child = document.getElementById("micid"+id);
             child.innerHTML = "mic_off";
             $('.micbut'+id).css("color", "red");
        }
    }

    function showMe(id) {
        $('#span'+id).toggle("drop",{direction: 'right'},500);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io();

            //understand button
        $(".understandbtn").click(function(){
            //reset the timer every 3 second of interval
            $('.actionBtnFloat').css('z-index','0');
```

//e_money

```
           var deduct = 100;
           var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;

           alert("Your money is: "+ newMoney);
           //i want to update here my e-money to the database with the value of the newMoney
```

//end

```
            clearTimeout(interval);
            //send the data to the server
            socket.emit('chat message', getUser());
            var interval = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.'+getUser()).fadeIn();
            },5000);
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('.cv'+msg).fadeOut();
            $('.'+msg).append('<img id="bulb" class="actImage" src="images/understand button.png" width="50" height="50">');
            $('#say'+msg).html('I understand');
            var intervals = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#say'+msg).html('');
                $('#bulb').remove();
                $('.cv'+msg).fadeIn();
            },5000);
        });

        //understand button end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't `require` in the browser.

There is a big difference between server-side JavaScript (NodeJS) and client-side JavaScript. Client-side JavaScript doesn't have a module system (yet), and you can't import/export things in a JavaScript file.

This is a huge disadvantage for JavaScript and creates many problems. For example, multiple JS files depend on the global namespace if they want to communicate with each other.

When NodeJS was introduced, its creators were aware of that problem and created the `require`/`module.exports` pattern. If you want to have the same behavior for client-side JavaScript, you have to use a module bundler, for example [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), etc.

Client-side JavaScript is used for user interaction, whereas NodeJS can pretty much do everything you want (reading/writing files on the server's hard drive, access a database, ...); but it can only operate on the server.

In client-side JavaScript, you can't require the `mongoose` module and therefore, you can't access a database on the server.

Moreover, the client-side JavaScript doesn't even need to access the server's database. It would be a security danger if it could.

If you really need to transfer data from the database to the browser, use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Of course, WebSockets are another possibility to transfer data between the client and the server. As you are already using them (socket.io, I suspect), here is an example of how to do that (I guess this is where you want to trigger the database update in the client-side code):

```js
$(".understandbtn").click(function () {
  //reset the timer every 3 second of interval
  $('.actionBtnFloat').css('z-index','0');
  var deduct = 100;
  var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;

  // send a message to the server that the e-money value has changed
  socket.emit('update e-money', {
    userName: {{user.name}}
    newMoney: newMoney
  });

  clearTimeout(interval);
  // send the data to the server
  socket.emit('chat message', getUser());
  var interval = setTimeout(function () {
    $('.'+getUser()).fadeIn();
  }, 5000);
});

socket.on('update e-money response', function (data) {
  alert("Your money is: "+ data.newMoney);
});

socket.on('update e-money error', function (data) {
  alert("Could not update your money: "+ data.error);
});
```

And on the server, you would do this:

```js
// perhaps you gave the socket server variable a different name than "socket" 
socket.on('update e-money', function (data) {
  var userName = data.userName;
  var newMoney = data.newMoney;
  var query = { username: userName };

  // is this the way you update entries in the database?
  User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { e_money: newMoney }, { upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      socket.emit('update e-money error', { error: err });
    }
    socket.emit('update e-money response', { newMoney: newMoney });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you help me out sir with this problem. I'll edit my question so that you'll fully understand what my problem is

Comment: I only know parts of your code, but my edited answer now contains an example.

Comment: okay ill try to implement that sir thank you very much i'll mark this as an answer thanks for the information

Comment: Hey sir i have a question . about this var query = { username: user.name };
Why user.name?

Comment: You have to somehow find the user that you want to update. I was just guessing that you can use `user.name` to retrieve a user's name. How do you identify a user object that is returned by `getUser()`?

Comment: i'm getting my username by doing this {{user.name}} like that

Comment: Should i find the id or its okay even if i just use the name to find the record?

Comment: The id would be even better.

Comment: and i guess sir there's something wrong here?
socket.emit('update e-money', {
    userName: {{user.name}}
    newMoney: newMoney
  });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147083/discussion-between-petermader-and-theginxx009).