# Use node package in script tag within html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, require

Can I work with node modules in a plain html/php file like this?

```
<script language="javascript">
   var duration = require('aac-duration');

   function getAudioDuration(file) {
      return duration(file);
   }
</script>
```

When I try it, it gives an 'require is not defined' error. I tried to find an easy solution, but couldn't find anything at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612571/require-function-inside-script-node-js